# Conditional Confidence.t Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, confidence-interval

I've tried to calculate a conditional t-distribution confidence interval in excel using the **IFS** function.
In my example column *V* is used to define the inequality conditions to select rows with values between 0 and 15 to calculate statistics on matching rows from column *AO*

I've tried calculating a conditional sample standard deviation *stdevs* as:

```
STDEV.S(IFS($V$8:$V$304>=0,$AO$8:$AO$304,$V$8:$V$304<15,$AO$8:$AO$304))
```

which I could then use within the ***CONFIDENCE.T*** function as:

```
=CONFIDENCE.T(0.05,stdevs,COUNTIFS($V$8:$V$304,">0",V$8:V$304,"<15"))
```

***My use of IFS to select a range to calculate *stdevs* failed. What is the problem?***

Other conditional statistics can be calculated built-in functions. For example, the conditional call for the average is:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($AO$8:$AO$93,Compare!$V$8:$V$93,>=0,$V$8:$V$93,<15)
```

and the equivalent conditional call for the count as used above is:

```
COUNTIFS($V$8:$V$304,">0",V$8:V$304,"<15")
```

It would be ideal if built-in *STDEVS.IFS* or  *CONFIDENCE.TIFS* function was avaiable or could be easily created by modifying the VBA used within the existing *AVERAGEIFS*.

***Is the VBA for AVERAGEIFS available for modification?***

Comment: You can't really edit existing functions, however, you can easily build custom functions. Do you have any experience with VBA? Another option, would be to use "CONFIDENCE.T" in conjunction with "FILTER()".

Comment: @CameronCritchlow Agreed. FILTER() and be used to implement the conditions. I have just enough experience with VBA to  avoid it unless there is no other alternative for Excel automation. These days I'd rather use Python using COM support via win32.client in [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I used **FILTER()** to specify a conditional range to calculate the standard deviation *stdevs* of the data sample:

```
=STDEV.S(FILTER(Compare!$AO$8:$AO$93,(Compare!$V$8:$V$93>=0) *(Compare!$V$8:$V$93<15), ""))
```

Next, I used **COUNTIFS()** to calculate the sample *size* for the same conditional range:

```
=COUNTIFS($V$8:$V$93,">0",V$8:V$93,"<15")
```

Finally, I used **CONFIDENCE.T** to calculate the conditional t-distribution for a 95% confidence interval (*alpha* = 0.05 significance level):

```
=CONFIDENCE.T(alpha,stdevs,size)
```